# How to convert combination of binary and ascii to human readable format in python

Tags: python, twisted

Below is my code for receiving data over socket.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Chat(LineReceiver):

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        print(line)

class ChatFactory(Factory):

   def __init__(self):
       self.users = {} # maps user names to Chat instances

   def buildProtocol(self, addr):
       return Chat()

reactor.listenTCP(9600,ChatFactory())
reactor.run()
```

I got response from the client with

```
b'$$\x00pP$\x91\x97\x01\xff\xff\x99\x99P000002.000,V,0000.0000,N,00000.0000,E,0.00,000.00,060180,,*09|||0000|0000,0000|000000113|00000[\x86'
```

which is combination of hex code and ascii, the location information is in ascii format.
**What is the best way to convert this data into human readable format?**

I need to parse **header, L and ID**.

```
<$$><L><ID><command><data><checksum><\r\n>
```

- header = 2 bytes and it will be in hex code representation of `0x24`
- L = 2 bytes and it is in the format of hex code .
- ID = 7 bytes and it is in the format of hex code .
- command = 2 bytes, it will be in hex code
- data will be in ascii format.
- checksum = 2 bytes and in hex code

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Location does not appear to be ASCII - it contains two `\x99` bytes at the start, and ends with `\x86`. Both of these fall outside of the ASCII range. Can you add to your question the expected output for the given input string?

Comment: My required output format will be `<$$><L><ID><data><checksum><\r\n>`  where $$ is header, L is lenght of the packet and is of 2bytes and in hex code, ID is of 7bytes and in hex code, data will be of maximum 100 bytes and in ascii code, checksum is of 2 bytes and in hex code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved just with the binary string:

```
import struct
header = line[:2]
if header!=b'$$':
    raise RuntimeError('Wrong header')
# Assumes you want two have 2 bytes, not one word
L = struct.unpack('BB',line[2:4])
ID = struct.unpack('7B', line[4:11])
location = line[11:]
print 'L={},{}, ID={}, location={}'.format(L[1],L[2], ''.join(str(b) for b in ID, location)
```

The link to struct is in the other answer

Comment: thanks it works. Just wanted to know . in my case L is the length of the whole packet and it is 2 bytes and is in hex code. So it will be struct.unpack('2B',line[2:4)) ? and I need to convert those hex code to decimal right? Correct me if it is wrong!

Comment: It is not a Hexcode - it is binary data that is represented as \x00 if the ASCII character for the value has no nice representation or shown as a character (eg. in case of $ for 0x24). The way I have shown is for to bytes as decimal numbers. But I guess the value is in word size (struct code 'h') and then you should really consult the struct help of Python - end it gets quite ugly in terms of endiness (as e-nouri mentioned).

Answer (score -1):

You can use `struct.unpack()`, but you have to know what you are gonna unpack (int, long, signed, etc.), the endiness if it is encoded on more that 1 bytes, ASCII are 7 bits, encoded on 1 byte.

Read more about struct [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html).

Comment: Can someone explains the downvote please, I want to know what is wrong ?